# MSB3411 Could not load Visual C++ component

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have MS Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and OS is Windows 7, and have nodeJs installed.I wanted to install socket.io using npm,but I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\NEW>npm install socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

> ws@0.4.25 install C:\Users\NEW\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-c
lient\node_modules\ws

> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Users\NEW\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\w
s>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.

MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\NEW\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-clie
nt\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]

MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\NEW\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-clie
nt\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]

socket.io@0.9.13 node_modules\socket.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.7.3
└── socket.io-client@0.9.11 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obf
uscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.25)
```

What might be the issue?How can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry to dig up an old question, but your question is the first result when I searched for "Socket.io VCBuild"

The solution I found, after stumbling around on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180012/npm-install-for-some-packages-sqlite3-socket-io-fail-with-error-msb8020-on-wi) was:

`npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2012`

**Update** from @petf-felzmann. If you're using VS 2015 you can use:

`npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2015`

Comment: working also with VS 2015: npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2015

Answer (score 1):

Install dotnet 3.5, so the websockets may be compiled

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the pre-requisite software to run `node-gyp`:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

You can configure version of Visual Studio used by `gyp` via an environment variable so you can avoid having to set the `--msvs_version=2012` property.

Examples:

- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012` for Visual Studio 2012
- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e` (the 'e' stands for 'express edition')

For the full list see 
 - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L209-294

This is still painful for Windows users of NodeJS as it assumes you have a copy of Visual Studio installed and many end users will never have this. So I'm lobbying Joyent to the encourage them to include web sockets as part of CORE node and also to possible ship a GNU gcc compiler as part of NodeJS install so we can permanently fix this problem.

Feel free to add your vote at:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8005#issuecomment-50545326

Answer (score -3):

I think I found it. Try:

```
npm install websocket@1.0.3
```

I found it [here](http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-node-js-websocket-echo-server/)

Comment: -1 He's getting an error installing the package he wants.  Installing a different package is hardly a real solution.