# can't install socket.io on windows 7 64bits

Tags: socket.io

I'm using windows 7 64bits , and I can't install socket.io
I'm following this tutorial :
https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/571/modded-socketio

I installed nodejs, and then I tried to write "npm install socket.io" in my cmd, but then I got this :

```
    Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

    C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install socket.io
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

    > ws@0.4.31 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\
    socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\nod
    e_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..
    \..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    socket.io@0.9.16 node_modules\socket.io
    ├── base64id@0.1.0
    ├── policyfile@0.0.4
    ├── redis@0.7.3
    └── socket.io-client@0.9.16 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, ws@0.4.31, a
    ctive-x-obfuscator@0.0.1)

    C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

I saw many similar issues, for linux mac and windows, but not a lot of answers. I tried to put system32 and nodejs and node_module in my path variable, but nothing. 
Can somebody help me please ?

edit 1 :

After using npm --force install socket.io, this is what I got (and it still doesn't work)

```
    Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm --force install socket.io
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.4.2.tg
z
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/-/active-x-obfuscato
r-0.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-0.4.31.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.4.2.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/-/active-x-obfuscato
r-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-0.4.31.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor/-/tinycolor-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options/-/options-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor/-/tinycolor-0.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-0.3.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/options/-/options-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-0.3.2.tgz

> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\
socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\nod
e_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..
\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
socket.io@0.9.16 node_modules\socket.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.7.3
└── socket.io-client@0.9.16 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, ws@0.4.31, a
ctive-x-obfuscator@0.0.1)

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

Comment: have you tried installing it in a different directory other than C:\ ?

Comment: yes, on my home computer I tried installing in E:\logiciels\socketsIO

Comment: ...yes I tried, but no it didn't worked...

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be due to OS etc. There might be any problems or restrictions on your internet. Because 'npm http 304' indicates there is some kind of error in your internet privileges etc

Comment: ok,  that's weird, it may explain why it doesn't work here at my office, but even at home on my own connexion it doesn't work... do you have any idea how to find a solution ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the problem as I said you might not have any privileges to fetch data through internet. But you can try to install it with npm --force install socket.io

Comment: I'm editing to add what I got in return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here

[NPM - Can't install socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469086/npm-cant-install-socket-io)

I tough it wouldn't work since I'm on windows7 and the guy is on mac, but it worked just fine :
npm install socket.io@"~0.8.1"