# Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio with node.js tools. My project won't start up and it's throwing the error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
```

This is a package I had previously installed, I figured maybe the global package directory might be a useful place to look, does anyone know where this is located?

I've narrowed it down to when I

```
require('mongoose')
```

I have the `mongoose` package, I have mongodb installed (correctly I think, and not the package but the actual thing, this stuff confuses the hell out of me), so not sure why it's complaining.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js cannot find module 'mongodb'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226410/node-js-cannot-find-module-mongodb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Quick Fix:**

The [mongoose `package.json` file](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/package.json) lists `mongodb` as a dependency. The `mongodb` package will be in the `mongoose` package's `node_modules` directory. This won't be a global install problem...

The easiest fix to try is to run this in the project's root directory:

```
npm install mongoose
```

If you require a specific version of `mongoose`, use this format:

```
npm install mongoose@x.y.z
```

...where `x.y.z` is the version, like `3.8.8`.

**If the Quick Fix Fails**

There's a good chance that the `mongodb` build failed during `mongoose` installation and will fail again because of an incompatible Windows VisualStudio/SDK version or a missing Python dependency.  This is based upon personal experience and from helping other Windows users with npm install failures...

If there *are* errors on a second try and they are from the `mongodb` build, the messages will usually be clear about what dependency isn't being met and what you can install to fix things.  If not, you can check the [node-gyp dependency requirements](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and verify you meet those requirements.

Comment: Thanks that's some useful steps, tried installing manually and hitting an error like `The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found`. I read somewhere that installing Visual Studio Express 2013 might help, after that a slightly different install error is shown `The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 cannot be found`.

Comment: Found the solution, you have to install with the option telling it to use 2012 tools e.g. `npm install --msvs_version=2012`, as outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180012/npm-install-for-some-packages-sqlite3-socket-io-fail-with-error-msb8020-on-wi).