# Unable to find module mongodb in simple node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

**TL;DR**: Following is a detailed explanation of the steps I followed to arrive at the **error**. To find the basic question, skip to the very bottom.

---

I'm following this book [addyosmani - backbone-fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-2-book-library---your-first-restful-backbone.js-app) for creating a simple backbone.js app with node server and mongodb as backend.

As instructed, I've installed the latest versions of Node.js from[nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/download/) and mongodb from [www.mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/) and ran mongodb by followed the [instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/).

Now as per the tutorial, I've created the following:

```
{ //package.json
  "name": "backbone-library",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A simple library application using Backbone",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.1.0",
    "path": "~0.4.9",
    "mongoose": "~3.5.5"
  }
}
```

at the root of my project and executed `npm install`, for some reason it didn't work out.

I further ventured and installed [express](http://expressjs.com/) [following these steps](http://expressjs.com/starter/installing.html):

```
npm init
npm install express --save
npm install express
```

this created the following package.json which I believe to be essentially the same as the one mentioned in tutorial:

```
{
  "name": "Backbone-Library",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A simple library application using Backbone",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^3.18.3",
    "mongoose": "^3.5.16",
    "path": "^0.4.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This created the very same folder structure which is mentioned in the tutorial:

```
node_modules
|_ .bin
|_ express
|_ mongoose
|_ path
```

and then I've successfully executed `npm install` without any errors.

---

Now once I [create a simple `server.js` file](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#create-a-simple-web-server) and try to execute it using the command `node server.js` I get the following error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\<-- path to project ->\Backbone-Library\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

(*I can provide the full trace if needed*).

I've found these [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226410/node-js-cannot-fine-module-mongodb) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260677/error-cannot-find-module-mongodb) regarding the same error, and the answers says that I've to install mongodb again using `npm`.

I've got confused because the book doesn't mention anything regarding this step.

I'm pretty new to everything I've mentioned here except backbone - `node.js`, `npm`, `mongodb` etc so I might be missing some basic concepts.

I'd like to know if it is possible to use the existing db which I installed previously rather than downloading and installing it again via `npm`.

If not, why is it required to install it again using `npm`, what is the difference between original installation and `npm` installation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original install installed the db itself on your machine. The npm install installs the package node.js needs to communicate with mongodb. NPM is like NuGet for .NET. You have a database, but still have to install the package for the framework to communicate to the database itself

Here is a sample on how to use mongodb module to connect to a mongo instance in node.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var query = { 'grade' : 100 };

        db.collection('grades').find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if(err) throw err;

            console.dir(docs);

            db.close();
        });
    });
```

Comment: So, `npm install mongodb` isn't installing the db itself..?

Comment: no it installs a package/module for node.js to know how to use mongodb and communicate with it. Think of it has a driver for node.js to work with mongodb

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a *database software*; similar to how MySQL is a software. Oftentimes your interactions with a database layer are managed by some sort of abstract library - in this case, the node module `mongoose`.

It sounds like you have `require('mongodb')`, when you should have `require('mongoose')`. This will bring in the `Mongoose` module, which is essentially a code library for interacting with your `MongoDB` database.

It sounds like you're confused a bit on terminology. If you have any questions, feel free to hit me up :)

Comment: that's if he wants to use mongoose. He can still use mongodb package

Comment: the `server.js` file is exactly as shown here http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#create-a-simple-web-server and it has `require('mongoose')` ...

Comment: Do you have MongoDB installed on your computer?

Comment: Could you put your full stack trace in a pastebin or something...I think that would help me out a bit

Comment: @JordanForeman Of course I'm confused with terminology or the basic usage of `npm`. `mongoose` has listed `mongodb` as their dependency in it's `package.json` does this mean the `mongoose` folder should in turn have another `node_modules` folder inside it which contains `mongodb`..? Is`npm install` in the root folder of my project supposed to install all listed dependencies, their dependencies, dependencies of their dependencies and so on..?

Comment: You're correct that installing any package should automagically install its dependencies recursively. MongoDB is a different kind of dependency being that it isn't (by definition) an NPM module. It sounds like one exists, but you're probably better served installing it standalone. The more I read your comments, the less I believe my answer is going to be helpful. It sounds like either your connection logic is broken, or some child dependencies aren't installing as expected...