# nodejs' ldapauth module install failure

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I have a nodejs application running on windows7 64bit. Now I want to install the ldapauth (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapauth) but when I do I get the following error during install. Please help!

```
C:\Programs\nodejsCloudant++>npm install ldapauth
npm WARN package.json make@0.0.0 No repository field.

> bcrypt@0.7.5 install C:\Programs\nodejsCloudant++\node_modules\ldapauth\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild
C:\Programs\nodejsCloudant++\node_modules\ldapauth\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: Access is denied.
gyp ERR! stack
```

Comment: The `bcrypt` package, that `ldapauth` depends on, has a [dependency on OpenSSL](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/tree/v0.7.6#dependencies) being installed. You may also have to [specify `--msvs_version=2012`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180012/npm-install-for-some-packages-sqlite3-socket-io-fail-with-error-msb8020-on-wi).

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know about the openSSL dependency. I followed instructions at https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/ to install node-gyp. 

    C:\Programs\nodejsCloudant++>node-gyp -v
v1.0.3

Comment: Please find the above log on brcypt installation